# Getting Error while Building Vue JS Docker Image

Tags: docker, vue.js

I followed Vue JS Documentation(mention below) and got this error while npm run build stage in docker file. How can i fix this issue. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html

Here is the output of Docker build command.

````
Step 1/9 : FROM node:lts-alpine
 ---> 211bb86587c9
Step 2/9 : RUN npm install -g http-server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f65931452226
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 83c737933ba1
Step 4/9 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ed13af8a79c0
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 26637a34a3eb
Step 6/9 : COPY . .
 ---> 2c0c51014389
Step 7/9 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in fa44981b7ceb
npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-26T08_32_52_748Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1```
````

Comment: Post your `package.json`

Comment: Can you run `npm run build` locally? Do you have a `build` script defined in your package.json?